# phonebook search in app crashes when a contact synced by facebook selected

Tags: android

im trying to fetch a contact in my app. it works fine for normal contacts but  my app crashes when i try selecting a contact in my phonebook synced with facebook (i.e facebook contacts). please help. thank you in advance.

this is pretty much my code dealing with phonebook

```
 public void onClickSelectContact(View btnSelectContact) {

        // using native contacts selection
        // Intent.ACTION_PICK = Pick an item from the data, returning what was selected.
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACTS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACTS && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + data.toString());
            uriContact = data.getData();

            retrieveContactName();
            retrieveContactNumber();
            retrieveContactPhoto();

        }
    }

    private void retrieveContactPhoto() {

        Bitmap photo = null;

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(getContentResolver(),
                    ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new Long(contactID)));

            if (inputStream != null) {
                photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_contact);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
            }

            assert inputStream != null;
            inputStream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void retrieveContactNumber() {



        // getting contacts ID
        Cursor cursorID = getContentResolver().query(uriContact,
                new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID},
                null, null, null);

        if (cursorID.moveToFirst()) {

            contactID = cursorID.getString(cursorID.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        }

        cursorID.close();

        Log.d(TAG, "Contact ID: " + contactID);

        // Using the contact ID now we will get contact phone number
        Cursor cursorPhone = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER},

                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " +
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + " = " +
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE,

                new String[]{contactID},
                null);

        if (cursorPhone.moveToFirst()) {
            contactNumber = cursorPhone.getString(cursorPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        }

        cursorPhone.close();

        Log.d(TAG, "Contact Phone Number: " + contactNumber);
    }

    private void retrieveContactName() {

        loanedTo = null;

        // querying contact data store
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriContact, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            // DISPLAY_NAME = The display name for the contact.
            // HAS_PHONE_NUMBER =   An indicator of whether this contact has at least one phone number.

            loanedTo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            personName.setText(loanedTo);
        }

        cursor.close();

        Log.d(TAG, "Contact Name: " + loanedTo);

    }
```

logcat displays

```
    02-05 18:32:34.382: E/AndroidRuntime(16628): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-05 18:32:34.382: E/AndroidRuntime(16628): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-05 18:32:34.382: E/AndroidRuntime(16628): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/1670i1213151574/3812 }} to activity {appytite.giveitback/appytite.giveitback.AddingItem}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null
02-05 18:32:34.382: E/AndroidRuntime(16628):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3145)
02-05 18:32:34.382: E/AndroidRuntime(16628):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3188)
02-05 18:32:34.382: E/AndroidRuntime(16628):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:134)
02-05 18:32:34.382: E/AndroidRuntime(16628):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
02-05 18:32:34.382: E/AndroidRuntime(16628):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-05 18:32:34.382: E/AndroidRuntime(16628):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-05 18:32:34.382: E/AndroidRuntime(16628):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4744)
02-05 18:32:34.382: E/AndroidRuntime(16628):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-05 18:32:34.382: E/AndroidRuntime(16628):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-05 18:32:34.382: E/AndroidRuntime(16628):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-05 18:32:34.382: E/AndroidRuntime(16628):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-05 18:32:34.382: E/AndroidRuntime(16628):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-05 18:32:34.382: E/AndroidRuntime(16628): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null
02-05 18:32:34.382: E/AndroidRuntime(16628):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:170)
02-05 18:32:34.382: E/AndroidRuntime(16628):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
02-05 18:32:34.382: E/AndroidRuntime(16628):    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:366)
02-05 18:32:34.382: E/AndroidRuntime(16628):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:370)
02-05 18:32:34.382: E/AndroidRuntime(16628):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:313)
02-05 18:32:34.382: E/AndroidRuntime(16628):    at appytite.giveitback.AddingItem.retrieveContactNumber(AddingItem.java:372)
02-05 18:32:34.382: E/AndroidRuntime(16628):    at appytite.giveitback.AddingItem.onActivityResult(AddingItem.java:324)
02-05 18:32:34.382: E/AndroidRuntime(16628):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5192)
02-05 18:32:34.382: E/AndroidRuntime(16628):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3141)
02-05 18:32:34.382: E/AndroidRuntime(16628):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: there is something wrong with it. my virtual device disconnects everytime before launching the app. i have to transfer it to my android device to run it, so i cant seem to work with logcat :(

do you have any clue whats going wrong with the code?

Comment: @Niek , the problem comes when i try selecting a contact synced by facebook. i just figured that out.
any idea why ?

Comment: I'd suggest you first get your logcat to work. Developing without it is definately a PITA.

Comment: i will. do you have any idea as it stands?

Comment: Unfortunately, without a stacktrace, debugging this is almost impossible.

Comment: i know. well thank you anyways :)

Comment: @niekHaarman please have a look at the logcat messages